# How to change specified image size in UIImageView with UISlider in Swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, uislider

I'm trying to use the `UISlider` to change specified image size in `UIImageView`.
The value range of the slider is 0 ~ 100.
So the idea is that if I move the slider smaller, a specified image shows smaller, and If I move the slider bigger, the image size getting bigger.

This is the case when the image getting smaller:
[getting smaller image by UISlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMfP3.png)

And this is the case when the image getting bigger:
[getting bigger image by UISlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG8Fl.png)

Can someone please help?

Comment: ok you can do it with taking a scrollview and imageview in it and use scrollview delegate methods to achieve this functionality

Comment: why you not use scroll view instead of image?

Comment: You mean Use scroll view instead of imageview? 
I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the slider's value range from .01 to 1.0 (.01 should work better than 0.)

Control-drag from your slider into your view controller and create an action on the slider's valueChanged event. Let's call it `sliderChanged`.

In the slider's action method, change the scale on the image view:

```
@IBOutlet myImageView: UIImageView*


@IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
  let scale = sender.value
  let transform = CGAffineTransform.scale(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
  myImageView.transform = transform
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add *Width* and *Aspect Ratio* constraints to your image view -and obviously the other desired needed constraints-:

[image]

In my example, these are the constraints for the image view:

[image]

Next, you could implemnt the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slider.maximumValue = 100.0
        slider.value = 0.0
        imageViewWidth.constant = 20
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        imageViewWidth.constant = CGFloat(20 + slider.value)
    }
}
```

the `imageViewWidth` IBOutlet will be the width constraint of your image view that you want to resize.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. This is what I wanted. And Can you realizes programmatically?

Comment: Glad to Help! "And Can you realizes programmatically?" I don't get :) do you still have any problem?

Comment: It's not realized by programmatically, But it works, Thanks to your effort, Ahmad.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update frames based on slider's value
2. Try multiplying UISlider's value with UIImageView's constraints